# What is going on inside the varimax function in R?

Tags: r, svd

I have been trying to figure out the core part of the `varimax` function in R. I found a [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Varimax_rotation) that writes out the algorithm. But why is `B <- t(x) %*% (z^3 - z %*% diag(drop(rep(1, p) %*% z^2))/p)` is computed? I also am not sure as to why SVD is computed of the matrix B. The iteration step is probably to maximize/minimize the variance, and the singular values would really be variances of Principal Components. But I am also unsure about that. I am pasting the whole code of `varimax` for convenience, but really the relevant part and therefore my question on what is actually happening under the hood, is within the for loop.

```
function (x, normalize = TRUE, eps = 1e-05) 
{
  nc <- ncol(x)
  if (nc < 2) 
    return(x)
  if (normalize) {
    sc <- sqrt(drop(apply(x, 1L, function(x) sum(x^2))))
    x <- x/sc
  }
  p <- nrow(x)
  TT <- diag(nc)
  d <- 0
  for (i in 1L:1000L) {
    z <- x %*% TT
    B <- t(x) %*% (z^3 - z %*% diag(drop(rep(1, p) %*% z^2))/p)
    sB <- La.svd(B)
    TT <- sB$u %*% sB$vt
    dpast <- d
    d <- sum(sB$d)
    if (d < dpast * (1 + eps)) 
      break
  }
  z <- x %*% TT
  if (normalize) 
    z <- z * sc
  dimnames(z) <- dimnames(x)
  class(z) <- "loadings"
  list(loadings = z, rotmat = TT)
}
```

Edit: The algorithm is available in the book "Factor Analysis of Data Matrices" by Holt, Rinehart and Winston and the actual sources can be found therein. This book is also cited with the varimax function in R.

Comment: Possibly helpful description of rotation in exploratory factor analysis: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273633238_What_is_Rotating_in_Exploratory_Factor_Analysis

Comment: Thanks. I know what should be happening theoretically, following Kaiser's work. But my question is regarding how it is computed in R, because also the matrix B has terms that could look like terms in the varimax objective function, it is still unclear.

Comment: I don't understand that code, but there's a possible simplification: `drop(rep(1, p) %*% z^2)` is just `colSums(z ^ 2)`.

Comment: Digging into the version history, it seems the code was written by Brian Ripley 17 years ago. Try asking him? https://github.com/wch/r-source/blame/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/R/factanal.R#L318

Comment: Yes part of the second term does seem to be the second term of Kaiser's varimax objective. I will try to contact Brian Ripley, that was a great help, thanks!